# Symbolic link to a non existing file

Tags: unix, symlink

I tried to create a symbolic link to a non existing file

```
ln -s non_existing_file.txt   $HOME/dir1/dir2/my_symbolic_link
```

Then I tried to write something in the non existing file using the symbolic link

```
vi $HOME/dir1/dir2/my_symbolic_link
```

Now after saving and exiting non_existing_file.txt is created under dir2.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Someone explain why is this question off-topic?

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's a question about using the Unix environment; https://unix.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

```
ln -s target linkpath
```

creates a symlink at `linkpath` which holds the name `target`. Operations on the symlink interpret the name `target` relative to the directory where the symlink resides, not the present working directory.

So, if you have a symlink holding, say, `../usr` in `/tmp/link-to-usr`, then `ls /tmp/link-to-usr` will list the contents of `/usr` (which is `/tmp/../usr`) regardless of where the `ls` command is executed.